# How to use the jQuery Cycle Plugin with WordPress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I have tried everything that I can think of. It shouldn't be this hard. Can some one please explain to me the process of using jQuery with WordPress (specifically jQuery Cycle Plugin)?

in header.php I have:

```
<?php
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle.all.min', '/wp-content/themes/andrewhavens/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('featured-work-slideshow', '/wp-content/themes/andrewhavens/featured-work-slideshow.js');
    wp_head();
?>
```

I have uploaded those two js files to my theme's directory.

In featured-work-slideshow.js I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#featured-works').cycle('fade');
});
```

And in my template, I have:

```
<div id="featured-works">
    <?php query_posts('category_name=featured-work&showposts=5'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="featured-work">
            <div class="featured-work-image-container" style="float:left; width:600px;">
                <?php $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homepage-image', true); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="500" height="300" style="margin-left:30px;">
            </div>
            <p style="float:left; width:300px;">
                <?php the_title(); ?><br />
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More!</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

throw a get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") to make your life easier

```
 <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle.all', get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js', array('jquery')); ?>
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that function existed. But why are you specifying a "stylesheet directory" when they are javascript files. Is there a "javascripts directory" function?

Comment: @Andrew  there is no specified `js`directory, but I would recommend using either [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

Answer (score 4):

I've figured it out. I accidentally forgot to specify the right path:

```
<?php
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle.all.min', '/wp-content/themes/andrewhavens/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('featured-work-slideshow', '/wp-content/themes/andrewhavens/featured-work-slideshow.js');
    wp_head();
?>
```

should have been

```
<?php
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle.all.min', '/wp-content/themes/andrewhavens/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', array('jquery'));
   wp_enqueue_script('featured-work-slideshow', '/wp-content/themes/andrewhavens/js/featured-work-slideshow.js');
   wp_head();
?>
```

otherwise, it works just fine